# Use CreateProcess to run bin files

Tags: c++

it's possible to run .bin like C# ?

C# using code such as that

```
        Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"test.bin";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.Start();
```

in c++ tried

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo; 

    STARTUPINFO StartupInfo; 
    char cmdArgs[] = "test.bin";

    ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
    StartupInfo.cb = sizeof StartupInfo;

    if (CreateProcess("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\runbin\\Release\\test.bin", cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo)){
        WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
        CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);

        printf("work!");
    }
    else{
        printf("The process could not be started...");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but not working with .bin

Comment: bin is not an executable file

Comment: i know but it any a executable file made in vb.net change exe to bin and just need to allowed user to run it from the c++ project and can't run it without using the c++ project